# PHP-Parsing Android sdk-repository XML

Tags: php, xml

How can parse XML with this structure :

```
<sdk:sdk-repository xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repository/7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--
 Generated on Thu Oct 22 10:16:34 PDT 2009 using eclair-sdk 17704: Platform. Addon. Tools. Doc. 
-->
    <sdk:platform>
<sdk:version>2.0</sdk:version>
<sdk:api-level>5</sdk:api-level>
<sdk:codename/>
<sdk:revision>01</sdk:revision>
<sdk:min-tools-rev>
<sdk:major>3</sdk:major>
</sdk:min-tools-rev>
<sdk:description>Android SDK Platform 2.0, revision 1</sdk:description>
<sdk:desc-url>http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.html</sdk:desc-url>
<sdk:obsolete/>
<sdk:archives>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="linux">
<sdk:size>75095268</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">be9be6a99ca32875c96ec7f91160ca9fce7e3c7d</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>android-2.0_r01-linux.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="macosx">
<sdk:size>74956356</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">2a866d0870dbba18e0503cd41e5fae988a21b314</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>android-2.0_r01-macosx.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
<sdk:archive arch="any" os="windows">
<sdk:size>76288040</sdk:size>
<sdk:checksum type="sha1">aeb623217ff88b87216d6eb7dbc846ed53f68f57</sdk:checksum>
<sdk:url>android-2.0_r01-windows.zip</sdk:url>
</sdk:archive>
</sdk:archives>
<sdk:layoutlib>
<sdk:api>4</sdk:api>
</sdk:layoutlib>
<sdk:uses-license ref="android-sdk-license"/>
</sdk:platform>
...
```

how can get **Version**? and **size**?
and even get Generated date ?( on Thu Oct 22 10:16:34 PDT 2009 using eclair-sdk 17704: Platform. Addon. Tools. Doc. ) for each SDK Platform(sdk:platform)

very very TNX

Comment: Your question as been answered over and over again here in SO. Just search here for `PHP parse xml namespace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing the XML and parsing the comment in the file are two completely separate things.

Regarding the XML itself, you can use PHP's [`SimpleXml`](http://php.net/simplexml) to parse it, but you'll have to remember to specify the namespace when accessing the children-elements.

We know we want namespaces, and we know which one we want, because each node that we're interested in is prefixed with `something:`. For example:

```
<sdk:version>2.0</sdk:version>
```

So, in this case, we are interested in the `sdk` namespace. You can find where the namespaces are defined in the top-most declaration node:

```
<sdk:sdk-repository xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repository/7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

This declares the `sdk` namespace to be `http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repository/7`. The `7` is a version number, so keep this in mind if you ever need to update to use different SDKs.

A small example of parsing the XML, using your sample XML, would be:

```
// load the file and create the XML element
$feed = file_get_contents("repository.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

// define the namespace you need to use (we want xmlns:sdk)
$sdk = $xml->children("http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repository/7");

// get the "platform" root element and start using it's nodes
$platform = $sdk->platform;

echo 'Version: ' . $platform->version . "<br />";
echo 'Description: ' . $platform->description . "<br />";
foreach ($platform->archives->archive as $archive) {
    echo 'Archive: ' . $archive->url . ", size: " . $archive->size . "<br />";
}
```

To match the `Generated on ...` line, you'll either need to use substring parsing *or* build a regex that can parse it. I'm opting for the latter option to save lines-of-code, but it's really up to you how you'd prefer to go about it.

If you wanted to use a regex, and this is very-specific to the output in your sample XML so you may need to adjust it to be more dynamic, you can use PHP's `preg_match` and a very verbose pattern:

```
$pattern = '/<!--[\r\n\s]*Generated on (.*) using eclair-sdk 17704: Platform\. Addon\. Tools\. Doc\.[\r\n\s]*-->/';

$comments = array();
preg_match($pattern, $feed, $comments);

echo $comments[1];
```

Output:

> Thu Oct 22 10:16:34 PDT 2009

Comment: output:   Version:
Description:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in index.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() index.php on line 16

Comment: @Vahid.Ahani Did you point `file_get_contents()` to the right file? Do you have an up-to-date version of PHP and is SimpleXml enabled?

Comment: tnx for your response. My PHP Version is 5.2.17 and Simplexml support is enabled and file is : $feed = file_get_contents('https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml'); tnx again.

Comment: @Vahid.Ahani In the remote file you specified, the xmlns:sdk namespace does not match the one posted in your sample XML; instead, it is `http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repository/8`. Just update my example above and it should output properly (you'll still need to modify it to loop through all platforms, but the example should work as a good base though).